# Can I use GWT frame widget inside a PopupPanel?

Tags: gwt, frame, popuppanel

I'd like to use a Frame widget inside a PopupPanel widget, so that in this popup I'm able to access some information from a different URL.

```
public class MyPopup extends PopupPanel {
    public MyPopup() {
        super(true);

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setUrl("http://google.com");
        frame.setWidth("200px");
        frame.setHeight("100px");

        setWidget(frame);
    }
}
```

When I debugged the code, I noticed that the page inside the frame was actually loaded, but I didn't see the content shown. The popup was transparent.

Anyone has experience on this? And any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used another way to implement my feature, maybe frame+popup is not good way. I will investigate further and see what is the problem.